# Declare an array type compatible with argument list of a given function?

Tags: typescript

```
function item(
    tag:     string,
    kind?:   string,
    name?:   string
) : string {

   return ` * ${tag}${kind ? ` [${kind}]` : ""}${name ? ` ${name}` : ""}`;
}

/*
 * Here, I need to declare the type ItemArgs that will be an array type
 * compatible with the argument list of the item() function.
 * 
 * How do I?
 */

function block(
    tag:        string,
    kind?:      string,
    name?:      string,
    ...items:   ItemArgs[]
) : string {

    // the items.map() call must compile
    return ["/**", item(tag, kind, name), ...items.map(item), " */"].join("\n");
}

// ... and this must compile too
const jsDocBlock : string = block(

    'typedef', 'Object', 'Foo',
    ['property', 'boolean', 'should'],
    ['property', undefined, 'something']
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ItemArgs` you can use the [`Parameters<F>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype):

```
function block(
    tag: string,
    kind?: string,
    name?: string,
    ...items: Parameters<typeof item>[]
): string {
    return [
        "/**",
        item(tag, kind, name),
        ...items.map(args => item(...args)),
        " */"
    ].join("\n");
}
```

Note also that I had to change your implementation, since `items.map(item)` will try to call `item` with the wrong arguments.  Each element of `items` is the tuple of parameters to `item`, which would be passed in as the first argument to `item` (and there are more arguments that [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes).

Anyway, this works now:

```
const jsDocBlock: string = block(
    'typedef', 'Object', 'Foo',
    ['property', 'boolean', 'should'],
    ['property', undefined, 'something']
);

console.log(jsDocBlock);
 // "/**
 // * typedef [Object] Foo
 // * property [boolean] should
 // * property something
 // */"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDKBTAtgCgFCL4qAQwHMAuRAZygCcYxiAaXfAazoBMB+cq2+p-IjCF0qbpRp1i2AJQ9J9RAG9szPNVRQQ1JAANEAKkQASJUWIBfU2zDtEnRPoDa1jhYC6+8gCJvVpcKi9o4mASKoFl6IvpEA3NgWqqCQsAiIAEYANnAQLDiC5vJ8jGqINlxFUgL4gWKV-KUAdM0oGBTkAAqE1OFo1BQAPFAAngAOqHDAyGjoAHxO7rL1xMqlGlo6iE6lgt4A9AYG3tWCeK1Y5gxlHFe1MienzY3nFI3ohKOY3cQUiAC8s2mGEwT2+FBk9x2+G8hj23lK7kaACs4HRMN4ADpgbwyeKJbAQBBURBIigAERyACFsrllv8MjS8qUAOQjcbsVDAZlXZkAeXSSNQ0G5iGZADE4HBuaUnMzRtQ4ONqCMRcz0pLMqhCGBVRQABZwECZdjM9wPWXyxWoZXDEXgDnAOiodg8ihwURQPVSU2yeIEolwTWNbLETCkikQak5Fi43B7PbRA4GOMJoxs52crb8wXQdyICVwFOGRCWpUjLbqwNasB5-WG41Foyl63lt0er30RtwxBAA)

Comment: I actually wrote the `map()` call correctly the first time and then I over-abbreviated.
Thanks for a quick answer, I don't now why I couldn't find `Parameters<>` in the docs. It's amazing that it could actually be implemented in TypeScript without introducting a new language feature.